# Convert SequenceFile as DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, sequencefile

I have a SequenceFile that I want to convert as DataFrame using Pyspark.

For that I am using the following code:

```
seq_file = sc.sequenceFile("products_sequencefile")
df = prod_seq.map(lambda a: str(a).split(",")).map(lambda a: (a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6])).toDF()
```

However, it gives me an output with some values with 'u:

```
+--------+-------+---+--------------------+---+------+--------------------+
|      _1|     _2| _3|                  _4| _5|    _6|                  _7|
+--------+-------+---+--------------------+---+------+--------------------+
|(u'1009'| u'1009| 45|Diamond Fear No E...|   |599.99|http://images.acm...|
```

Am I doing the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use toDF directly?

```
df = sc.sequenceFile("products_sequencefile").toDF('key', 'value')
ncols = 6    # set the ncols here as appropriate
df = df.select(
    'key',
    *[F.split(F.col('value'), ',')[i] for i in range(ncols)]
)
```

Comment: I've to split by "," in order to get all the columns, with toDF() direclty I will have two columns: the key and the rest of the values

Comment: @PedroAlves see edited answer? I splitted the values using comma delimiter after reading into dataframe